# Python 3.5 executable with Excel COM objects

Tags: python, excel, vba, compilation, executable

I have a Python code that opens up an Excel file. Uses one of the VBA functions in there to retrieve some data. And do some analysis on that data. All of this works on my computer. It also works when I compile it using PyInstaller into an EXE.

However, when distributing this EXE to a colleague that has nothing Python related installed, but only Excel, it does not work. I suspect it has something to do with working with Excel because of the error message.

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
  File "Check.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: <-2146777998, 'OLE error 0x800ac472', None, None>
Failed to execute script Check
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Because I have compiled it into an executable

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party library in the solution? If so, PyInstaller works with these out of the box. https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages.  I'm not overly familiar with PyInstaller, but you may need to configure the compiler to include any 3rd party libs.